# Solve the following sequence equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$${1\over4⋅8} +{1\over12⋅8}+ {1\over6⋅12}+...+{1\over4n(4n+4)}+{1\over16(n+1)}={1\over16}  $$
I have tried finding a reccurence formula or,at least ,prove the given one(the last two terms),but i failed terribly.Which is the reccurence formual for the given summation?

Comment: Move the last part to the other side, then prove by induction that: $${1\over4⋅8} +{1\over12⋅8}+ {1\over6⋅12}+...+{1\over4n(4n+4)}+={1\over16}-{1\over16(n+1)}$$

Comment: by which rule does $${1\over12*6}$$stand?In addition $$P(1):{1\over4*8} !={1\over16}-{1\over32}$$

Comment: Check your math. $\frac{1}{4\cdot 8}=\frac{1}{32}=\frac{1}{16}-\frac{1}{32}$. No idea what you mean by "by which rule does..." Be specific, and check your math.

Comment: my mistake, i apologise